# Memory leak org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem 1582384

Tags: jboss, redhat, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

We have a large number of objects created for org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem ,

We are using 6.4.0.GA with jre 1.7.0_40-b43 and Windows Server 2008 R2

Below is screenshot from yourkit :

[huge number of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4729.png)

Comment: Please attach the image along with your question instead of putting a link.

Comment: pls upgrade to 6.4.22 many fixes were done concerning org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem on 6.4